# How to tell which enum template parameter was used without actually storing that enum in one of the class attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11

It is not the first time I hit it. This time I was playing with the "binary angle"  class (unsigned integer is mapped into a 0-360deg or 0-180deg circle). Different objects span on different ranges. Some times it is 0-360 and some objects angles are -180 - +180 . I want it be done automatically when the object is cast to "arithmetic" values in degrees or radians.
I am storing the type of the "span" as an enum attribute of the class and it works, but I think it is wrong. There should be way to statically  test that template parameter.

I know how to use static checks like "is_arithmetic", "is_unsigned", etc. But I can not find what I am looking for.

enum declaration:

```cpp
enum cycle {
    FULL,            ///<  0 to 360deg
    HALF,            ///<  0 to 180deg
    FULL_SYMMETRIC,  ///<  -180deg to 180deg
    HALF_SYMMETRIC   ///<  -90deg to 90deg
};
```

class declaration:

```
/// Binary angle representation with conversion to/from DEG and RAD
template<typename U = uint32_t, enum cycle c = FULL>
class angle {
    U bin_angle;
    static const enum cycle type = c;
public:
```

and the degree/radians extraction member function

```
    /// Get current value in degrees or, optionally, in radians represented
    /// by the floating point type D
    template<typename D>
    D get(enum angle_units au = DEG) const {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<D>::value,
                      "The angle can only be requested as an arithmetic type");
        D circle_ang = cycle_span<D>(type);

        D ang = D(0);
        if (bin_angle != U(0)) {
            // XXX there must be a better way than to use long double
            long double ratio =
                    (long double) (maxU()) / (long double) (bin_angle);
            ang = (circle_ang) / D(ratio);
        }

        if (ang > cycle_end<D>(type)) {
            ang -= circle_ang;
        }

        if (au == RAD) {
            ang = deg2rad<D>(ang);
        }

        return ang;
    }
```

is  there a better way?

Comment: You'd simplify your problem by introducing an `angle` class and think about how to handle that.

Comment: What for do you have to store the enum in a member? `c` is a template parameter of the class template which `get()` is a member of. You can simply use `c` instead of `type`!?

Comment: @Michael Kenzel Thank you!  Some times it is so obvious and so simple  ... you do not even bother to try it. 
... it works!

Answer (score 0):

Michael Kenzel is right -- it was one of those "Dah"  moments. The code was changed to

```
// Binary angle representation with conversion to/from DEG and RAD
template<typename U = uint32_t, enum cycle span = FULL>
class angle {
    U bin_angle;


public:
```

and

```
    /// Get current value in degrees or, optionally, in radians represented
    /// by the floating point type D
    template<typename D>
    D get(enum angle_units au = DEG) const {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<D>::value,
                      "The angle can only be requested as an arithmetic type");
        D circle_ang = cycle_span<D>(span);

        D ang = D(0);
        if (bin_angle != U(0)) {
            // XXX there must be a better way than to use long double
            long double ratio =
                    (long double) (maxU<U>()) / (long double) (bin_angle);
            ang = (circle_ang) / D(ratio);
        }

        if (ang > cycle_end<D>(span)) {
            ang -= circle_ang;
        }

        if (au == RAD) {
            ang = deg2rad<D>(ang);
        }

        return ang;
    }
```

and it works just like before. It did'n not even occur to me that the template parameter can be used as an attribute or a variable.

Comment: you also can use it as a parameter of declaration or of `using\typedef` for an `integral_constant` if you need to have access to used `enum` value from outside. Note  that i's compile-time, so you can use it with `constexpr` expressions\functions.